# product list not responsive within responsive theme

Tags: magento-1.9

My Magento website www.buitengewoonbier.nl has a responsive theme. However if the website is visited with a mobile device the product list seems not to be responsive. So if you turn the mobile device to landscape more products show up.

Doe anyone know where to look and how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

If your referring to the product list on your category page
`app/design/frontend/YOURTHEME/template/catalog/product/list.phtml`

Comment: What was the point of the neg? The question is vague and the poster clearly asked "where to look".

Comment: In fact, I agree